# Flask Abort(403) Forbidden error message is said to be Forbidden, not letting me call it

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I am creating a blog with users, and adding authentication to some pages, requiring the user that is logged in to be admin to access certain pages. Below is the decorated function to check if the user is admin:

```
def admin_only(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            user_id = current_user.id
        except:
            user_id = 0

        if user_id == 1:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return abort(403)

    return decorated_function()
```

I get the below error message:

```
werkzeug.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden: You don't have the permission to access the requested resource. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.
```

I have imported abort from flask so not 100% sure why it is saying it is forbidden. Any tips, thanks in advance!

Comment: Presumably the code is calling `abort(403)`.  Where is `current_user` defined?

Comment: Pycharm gives an Exit Code 1, implying that it was not the expected outcome. current_user is defined in the other functions which use this decorated function

Comment: Remove the `try/except` from around the user_id assignment.  I bet you're getting an unknown variable exception.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it should be `abort(403)` and not `return abort(403)`

[abort](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.abort) will raise an exception for the given status code (403) and an exception implicitly does a return

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the parentheses from the final returned decorated function. Make it `return decorated_function` rather than `return decorated_function()`